# Load http page from C++ to trigger events

Tags: c++, http

I am trying to trigger an event on an embedded device (that runs a web server). This event can only be triggered by accessing a web page (HTTP protocol). So I just need to load a web page (for now I do it simply by copying the url link in my browser) to trigger the event I want (and I don't care about the content of the page).

What is the simplest way to do that in a C++ application running on a Linux (redhat) system ?

Do I have to use sockets ? Or is there a simpler way ?

Comment: you can take a look at [C++ Rest SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk), which was updated recently.

Answer (score 3):

For my money, [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), with its "easy" interface, is the way to go.

Comment: I agree with @cynic. Libcurl is the way to go on this one. Easy to use and very portable.